# Javascript evaluation time by the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, kendo-ui

We are trying to improve performance of our javascript files loading in the browser. Our own javascript files are pretty simple and small but bigger libraries like jQuery and KendoUI take quite a few milliseconds to evaluate and we would like to try to reduce that if possible.

jquery min js evaluates in around 51ms
kendoui custom min takes around 188ms

[image]

Any thoughts if there is anyway to bring this down or perhaps even somehow cache on the browser the evaluation result of these pretty static files?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my web.config I had the following lines, that were preventing these files to get cached

```
<customHeaders>
    <!--DISABLE CACHE-->
    <add name="Cache-Control" value="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
    <add name="Pragma" value="no-cache" />
    <add name="Expires" value="0" />
  </customHeaders>
```

As soon as I deleted this block, it started caching.

Additionally, you may want to take a look at this page: http://www.metatags.info/meta_http_equiv_cache_control

Comment: Thanks for the response Mario. Caching of the file is working ok but whether the file is cached or not it always takes those 188ms to evaluate the JS file. I'm guessing this is the browser takes for reading and executing the JS file